# Data model allowing queries against sub-entities

Tags: google-app-engine, data-modeling

I'm trying to get my head around designing a data model for app engine's HRD datastore.

There are two entities, call one `Food` and the other `Ingredient`. Each `Food` can have multiple `Ingredients`. Each `Ingredient` is unique in respect to all the other `Ingredient`s in all other `Food`s. Each `Ingredient` has an `amount` property.

I want to be able to updated a `Food` and all its `Ingredients` as a single consistent unit and yet be able to query against all `Ingredient`s of all `Food`s by the `amount` property.

Since I want to query against all `Ingredients`, I need to store them without an ancestor key. The problem is that doing so stops me from being able to perform strongly consistent updates to a batch of them associated with a single `Food`. Consequently, if two updates are made to a `Food` back to back, the state of the `Ingredients` is no longer guaranteed to be consistent, not even eventually.

I cannot think of any solution, not even with background tasks and versioned entities that can make the above guarantee.

Comment: Why do you state that you need to store them without an ancestor key? You can still query against all Ingredients even if each Ingredient has a Food parent.

Comment: Oh right! That should solve the problem, except doesn't the limit of 1 write/s apply here? In other words, an update to a `Food` can result in a dozen `Ingredient`s changing within a single entity group.

Comment: Yes, that is a constraint you'll need to work around. This document may help you https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/scaling/contention. I'll add my comment as an answer since it seems to have answered your question.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the write limit. It applies to transactions, not individual writes.

Comment: +1. I assumed, given the statement "I want to be able to updated a Food and all its Ingredients as a single consistent unit", that transactions were being used

Comment: Yep, seems that way (the appengine docs are not well written - for instance there is not a single mention of one transaction per second anywhere, it simply says _write_).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can still query against all Ingredients even if each Ingredient has a Food parent.